# Calculate Newey-West standard errors without an an lm object in R

Tags: r, standard-error

**Update -- I closed this question and [posted on crossvalidated.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5351/calculate-newey-west-standard-errors-without-an-an-lm-object-in-r).**

I have found some good information on using the `sandwich` package and the `NeweyWest()` function to find heteroskedastic autocorrelation consistent (HAC) standard errors.

But `NeweyWest()` only takes `lm` objects.

```
> library(sandwich)
> NeweyWest(rnorm(100))
Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
>
```

I frequently get vectors of returns unassociated with a linear regression for which I would like to find HAC standard errors. Any ideas? Should I write my own? Thanks!

Comment: some self sufficient code would be greatly appreciated. The code you give now doesn't make sense at all. How would one calculate a HAC **covariance matrix** on a vector? NeweyWest doesn't give you standard errors at all. You might want to try your luck at http://www.crossvalidated.com , but give a bit more information on what exactly you try to accomplish.

Comment: @joris - thanks, I will try cv when I get back to a computer. But you can calc a standard error for a vector. I could use sd(), but that would assume homoscedasticity and not autocorrelated. If I had a weak autocorrelation, then sd() would underestimate the error.

Comment: could you add links to/from CrossValidated and close one of the questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been a slight misunderstanding. I was thinking in terms of residuals, but what you asked is the standard error of the mean. That's easily obtained by modelling your vector against the intercept, or :

```
NeweyWest(lm(rnorm(100)~1))
```

For the standard deviation :

```
x <- rnorm(100)
NeweyWest(lm(x~1))*length(x)
```

Sorry for the misunderstanding, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for the help! In hindsight my questions never hit the spot. You solution seems like it should work, but it gives a really small std err. I'll post more repeatable code above.

Comment: @richardh : The standard error is indeed pretty small. The standard deviation is calculated by multiplying with the number of observations, as shown in the edited code. But I'm still not sure if that is what you are looking for. Estimating the standard deviation based on a variance-covariance matrix of a model is not exactly the most standard way. I think you might reconsider using the NeweyWest function and ask at CV for a more appropriate approach.

Comment: Good call. Thanks! Is the proper etiquette to delete this? Or leave it open so that someone can follow the thread to crossvalidated.com?

Comment: @richardh: I'd leave it open and add a link to crossvalidated. The programming question is answered, the statistics question might interest other people. Besides, I don't think you can delete the question after answers have been given.